# Independent and Identically Distributed RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Why is it that if two distributions $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are identical that they need to have the same parameter before they are independent? If they don't have the same parameter then how will the likelihood of one event occurring affect the likelihood of another occurring?

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ can have different distributions and still be independent. The probability of my winning the lotto and you rolling a $6$ on a die are independent. The term iid. is a convenient way of describing a collection of similar events that are independent.

Comment: Moreover, two r.v. $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be dependent even if they have the same parameters...

Comment: To build on @copper.hat's last point: ``i.i.d.`` does **not** mean "independent." It stands for "**i**ndependent and **i**dentically **d**istributed", which indeed requires *both* independence and same distribution (by definition).

Comment: Why then is it that my notes for insurance say that $S_{i}'s$, where $S_{i}$ is a compound distribution, are independent because they have different parameter values?

Comment: Kid Cudi: we cannot comment on your notes without knowing what they exactly say.

Comment: Claim from $i-th$ policy, $S_{i}$ follows Compound poisson distribution with Lambda,  we assume Lambda 's are iid.

Comment: @KidCudi sounds like they’re assuming the parameters *themselves* are IIDRVs not just (unknown or known) constants.

Comment: My 2 cents: I observe Clement is asking for reasons for your original statement "are independent because they have different parameter values"; but your response provides the quote "$S_i$ follows Compound Poisson distribution with $\lambda$, we assume $\lambda$s are iid." This quote does not seem related to that original statement.  Also, it does not assert dependence because of something else.